# Array into Label in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, label

I made some basic C++ program and I can not understand why it crashes when I try to put my array into Label and if array contains more, than 63 elements included.

This is how I declarated my array as a global variable:

```
int n;
int *array = new int[n];
```

And this is my code `on_pushButton_clicked()`:

```
n = ui->lineEdit->text().toInt();
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    ui->label_3->setText(ui->label_3->text() + QString::number(array[i]) + " ");
}
```

It works just with less than 63 elements and I have no idea why.

Comment: You should initialize `n` with a meaningful value before allocating `array`. (Or even better, not use a C-style array at all)

Comment: Yes, you were right! I added `array = new int[n];` just after `n = ui->lineEdit->text().toInt();`. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should initialize `n` with a meaningful value before allocating `array`. (Or even better, not use a C-style array at all). (с) [Frank Osterfeld](https://stackoverflow.com/users/299399/frank-osterfeld)